# API to API File Transfer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, google-drive-api, file-transfer

I need to transfer 1000's of files (images, pdf's) from one third party API service to the google drive API service. I have the auth working for each API.

My question is can this be done directly?
i.e. my code accesses a list of files in the first API and iterates through the list, transferring each to the google API service without the need for intermediate storage like for instance and AWS S3 bucket. The main reason for this is data transfer / bandwidth costs for storing to and transferring from AWS S3 (or equivalent service).

I am thinking of using a nodeJS backend and angular frontend for the app creation btw.

Comment: I think that if you can retrieve the files from `one third party API service`, the files can be uploaded to Google Drive using Drive API with node.js. In your situation, can I ask you about the maximum file size of the files you want to transfer?

Comment: You probably want to implement some kind of pagination logic so you are only processing so many at a time.  Do the files need to be displayed by the UI (for instance show the images and pdfs as thumbnails)?  If so, you may want to create an Angular Service with an rxjs observable that receives and stores a set number of these in say a map variable that will persist.   If you aren't displaying them, you probably won't want to store them client-side, I don't see why you couldn't do it all in node.js backend

Comment: @Tanaike I don't think I can enforce a max file size. I need to sync whatever files are in A to B

Comment: @Katherine Yeah I don't really need to show the files in the ui at all. Probably some metadata like number of files to synced out of total files,errors with files etc...

Answer (score 1):

**Ideas:**

**Hint:** Leverage Nodejs Native Stream API (Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html ).

**Note:** we may not need the Angular UI/FE layer if the user interaction is not needed

---

**Proposal:**

> Have one api to serve list of files(meta) to UI that post it to user
> user select a file or multiple files name which call API that is
> capable for transfer for files from storage one to other using Native
> nodejs Streams instead of storing into in memory buffer
>
> **Note:** check for gdrive and the 3rd party api file push quotas for
> heavy data transfer without throttling

Comment: Thanks. I will try this in a POC using 'Native nodejs Streams'